# How to replace the white in an image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, image-manipulation, pinterest

Pinterest (here is an [example](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/AW8UxQAbw_XNAHKo1Uvf7z6BFMF63Za1O0dW1uPuHtnDgBP2IHJ6KTE/)) and some other sites replace the white in their images with a gray color.  They do that for all of their images and it seems to be on the client side.

Is this possible using Javascript, or is there another way they are doing this?

Comment: Have you tried any kind of research or experimentation to see if this is possible?

Comment: @BenBeck Yeah, I've looked around and not been able to find anything.  I figured I was using the wrong search terms.

Comment: They're not changing the image, they're adding an overlay using JS

Comment: @ic3b3rg thanks.  I didn't realize that.  Do you know anywhere you could point me to that might explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick & dirty example that might help get you started:

```js
$('#container').on("mouseenter mouseleave", () => {
  $('.overlay').toggle(); 
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: .25;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/600x742q90/537/xAgiLR.jpg" width="200px" height="247px">
  <div class="overlay" />
</div>
```